# Reorder Multi-indexed dataframe columns based on reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe with names attached to the column levels. 
The data table looks something like this:
(df1)

```
                        TIME                    
         TMC    111N1   111P2   111N3   111P4   
DATE    EPOCH                   
          0     143     113      103    NaN 
          1     183     NaN      NaN    NaN 
          2     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN 
          3     143     NaN      NaN    NaN
```

I'd like to shuffle the columns around so that they match the order specified by the rows index of a reference dataframe (df2):

```
        A1  A2  A3    A4    A5
 Name                                                                               
 111N3  PA  PL  er  0.75543 35
 111P4  PA  PL  er  0.09413 35
 111N1  PA  PL  er  4.21557 35
 111P2  PA  PL  er  1.31989 35
```

i.e. the result should be (df3):

```
                        TIME                    
         TMC    111N3   111P4   111N1   111P2   
DATE    EPOCH                   
          0     103     NaN      143    113 
          1     NaN     NaN      183    NaN 
          2     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN 
          3     NaN     NaN      143    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

`reindex_axis` will use the labels from the other dataframe and let you specific the axis to reindex and also a particular level:

```
df1.reindex_axis(df2.index, axis=1, level=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. i just made a slight change to: 'df1.reindex_axis(df2.index, axis=1, level=1)'

Comment: This answer should be highly viewed. Superb !

Here are some bad answers for the same problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194610/how-can-i-reorder-multi-indexed-dataframe-columns-at-a-specific-level

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046075/how-to-re-order-the-multi-index-columns-using-pandas

Comment: reindex_axis is deprecated since version 0.21.0: Use reindex instead.