# How to re-order the multi-index columns using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

[Table is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Hmo.png)

code:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['France']*4+['China']*4,
                   'Progress':['Develop','Middle','Operate','Start']*2,
                   'NumTrans':np.random.randint(100,900,8),
                   'TransValue':np.random.randint(10000,9999999,8)})

dff = dff.set_index(['Country','Progress']).T
```

Data and code are shown above.

I want to know is there any way to re-order the "Progress" as start-develop-middle-operate using Python.

I tried using map function and set each stage with a number, but cannot extract "Progress" from multi-index

Thanks!

Comment: Answered here in the best way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570679/reorder-multi-indexed-dataframe-columns-based-on-reference?rq=1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### `reindex`

You can specify a level to reindex on

```
cats = ['Start', 'Develop', 'Middle', 'Operate']
dff.reindex(cats, axis=1, level=1)

Country      France                              China                         
Progress      Start  Develop   Middle  Operate   Start Develop  Middle  Operate
NumTrans        772      832      494      793     750     722     818      684
TransValue  7363187  2578816  9764430  4863178  159777  840700  978816  9674337
```

---

#### `set_levels` with `CategoricalIndex`

You can define the order of the second level and then sort.

```
lvl1 = dff.columns.levels[1]
cats = ['Start', 'Develop', 'Middle', 'Operate']
cati = pd.CategoricalIndex(
  lvl1,
  categories=cats,
  ordered=True
)
dff.columns.set_levels(
  cati, level=1, inplace=True  
)

dff.sort_index(1)

Country      China                            France                           
Progress     Start Develop  Middle  Operate    Start  Develop   Middle  Operate
NumTrans       750     722     818      684      772      832      494      793
TransValue  159777  840700  978816  9674337  7363187  2578816  9764430  4863178
```

Comment: This is Gold. And you're a saviour. Thank you @piRSquared

Comment: Very simple answer with respect to other ones I've seen. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! In my case I used `df.reindex(cats, axis=1, level=0)` to get the shape that I wanted.